# I want to extract numbers which are started with $ sign. for ex: $545

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, numbers

```
import re
test = 'We four guys, live at 2nd street of Malibeu. I had a cash of $248 in my pocket. I got a ticket with serial number ABC1234.'

arr = []
arr = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', test)
print(arr)
```

I've tried like this to get numbers from a string. but it only returns string.

I want to get `$`sign too before the number.
and I need to print Serial number like
`ABC1234`

the output I'm getting is:

```
[2, 248, 1234]
```

I need output like:

with `$` sign:

```
$248
```

with `ABC`:

```
ABC1234
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: since You are already using regex, You might as well just look up the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), seems You haven't even tried to include anything else other than number in Your regex

Comment: Do you want the serial number to start only with ABC or can the serial number start with other letters? And also, do you only want to use `regex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code to group the $ and the ABC together:

```py
import re
test = 'We four guys, live at 2nd street of Malibeu. I had a cash of $248 in my pocket. I got a ticket with serial number ABC1234.'

arr = []
arr = re.findall(r'(?:\$|ABC)[0-9]+', test)
print(arr)
```

and the result is `['$248', 'ABC1234']`

Answer (score 0):

You can optionally match either `$` or uppercase chars before matching the digits.

```
(?:\$|\b[A-Z]+)?\d+
```

The pattern matches

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\$` Match $
  - `|` Or
  - `\b[A-Z]+` A word boundary, match 1+ uppercase chars
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v4oOgY/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/V9zwJp)

Example

```
import re
test = 'We four guys, live at 2nd street of Malibeu. I had a cash of $248 in my pocket. I got a ticket with serial number ABC1234.'

arr = re.findall(r'(?:\$|\b[A-Z]+)?\d+', test)
print(arr)
```

Output

```
['2', '$248', 'ABC1234']
```

---

If you don't want to match numbers only, the non capture group should not be optional, and you can add a word boundary `\b` at the end to prevent a partial match:

```
 (?:\$|\b[A-Z]+)\d+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/icVdbj/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6upvmA)

```
import re
test = 'We four guys, live at 2nd street of Malibeu. I had a cash of $248 in my pocket. I got a ticket with serial number ABC1234.'

arr = re.findall(r'(?:\$|\b[A-Z]+)\d+\b', test)
print(arr)
```

Output

```
['$248', 'ABC1234']
```

Comment: OP doesn't want `2` as output

Comment: @PCM Where do you read that? Maybe I have missed it.

Comment: Yeah check the question, output must be - `$248` and `ABC1234`

Comment: @PCM I have added another pattern to not match digits only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do not need `re` module for the `$` symbols. Because there is an inbuilt python method you can use - `.startswith` and `.endswith`. Here is how you use it -

```
test = '...'

for i in test.split():
    if i.startswith('$'):
        print('With $ sign: ',i)

    if i.startswith('ABC'):
        print('With ABC: ',i)
```

You could use  `.startswith` for the serial number too. But if the letters in the serial number are random and not starting with 'ABC' **always**, you could use `re`. So, you need to match the strings that have **numbers trailing after it**, then you can do this -

```
a = re.findall(r'[a-z]+[\d]+|[A-Z]+[\d]+',test)
print(a)
```

**Here**,

`[a-z]+[\d]+` matches any string with small letters and numbers. **for eg- abc1200, ABC1234.** If you do not need small letters, then remove them. But, just to make sure, I added them.

`|` is `Or` operator in regex

`[A-Z]+[\d]+` matches any string with capital letters and numbers. This is the **main** part of the pattern that you need.

As I said, if you do not need matching small letters, then remove `[a-z]+[\d]+` and `|`

So,
**Use `.startswith` for the '$' and use `re` for the 'Serial Numbers'**